# regex match for startswith

Tags: python, regex, startswith

Given a random length of filepath, how to regex for something in the middle:

```
name = 'path/to/../../foo/file.py'
```

something like this:

```
In [2]: name.startswith('.*/foo/')
Out[2]: False
```

Comment: Have you looked into using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) ?

Comment: Something _known_ like a literal ?

Comment: `re.match('.*/foo/', name)`

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747968/getting-file-list-using-glob-in-python/33748006

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `re` Use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) as the way to do it.

```
import glob
for filename in glob.iglob('C:\Users\Desktop\**\Start\c*'):
    print(filename)
```

**output**

```
C:\Users\Desktop\screenshoots\Start\cmr(1).PNG
C:\Users\Desktop\screenshoots\Start\cmr(2).PNG
C:\Users\Desktop\screenshoots\Start\cmr(3).PNG
```