# Get file names into list using glob

Tags: python

I want to load file names into an array to load images from their paths. This job is done by the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747968/getting-file-list-using-glob-in-python). My code is something like this

```
fileNames = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.jpg"))
```

My filenames are something similar to this pattern

```
{videoNo}_{frameNo}_{patchNo).jpg
```

For example their names are like this

```
1_1_1.jpg
1_1_2.jpg
1_1_3.jpg
.
.
.
10_1_1.jpg
10_1_2.jpg
```

When I load filenames into `fileNames` array, they are like this

```
10_1_1.jpg
10_1_2.jpg
.
.
.
1_1_1.jpg
1_1_2.jpg
1_1_3.jpg
```

As far as I know this is because the asci code for `_` is bigger than `0` and because of that the list of names is not sorted! I must work with the sorted list. Can anyone give me a hand here?

**EDIT**
Please notice that the sorted of these file names

```
 ["1_1_1.jpg", "10_1_3.jpg", "1_1_2.jpg", "10_1_2.jpg", "1_1_3.jpg", "1_20_1", "1_2_1", "1_14_1"]
```

is similar to this sorted list

```
 ["1_1_1.jpg", "1_1_2.jpg", "1_1_3.jpg", "1_2_1.jpg", "1_14_1", "1_20_1", "10_1_2.jpg", "10_1_3"]
```

Comment: I think ‘os.listdir’ would achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to extract the numbers from the file names and sort by those:

```
>>> import re
>>> files = ["10_1_3.jpg", "1_10_2.jpg", "3_1_1.jpg", "30_1_2.jpg"]
>>> sorted(files, key=lambda f: tuple(map(int, re.findall(r"\d+", f))))
['1_10_2.jpg', '3_1_1.jpg', '10_1_3.jpg', '30_1_2.jpg']
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`sorted` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`list.sort` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) both take a *key* parameter that specifies how to do the sorting. If you want to sort by the numbers in the name (i.e. videoNo, then frameNo, then patchNo) you can split each name into these numbers:

```
fileNames = sorted(
    glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.jpg")),
    key=lambda item: [
        int(part) for part in os.path.splitext(item)[0].split('_')
    ],
)
```

The splitting strips off the `.jpg` extension, then cuts the name on each `_`. Conversion to `int` is needed because strings use lexicographic sorting, e.g. `"2" > "10"`.